# Using cURL to replicate browser request

Tags: bash, cookies, curl

I'm trying to use cURL to get data to the form an URL:

```
http://example.com/site-explorer/get_overview_text_data.php?data_type=refdomains_stats&hash=19a53c6b9aab3917d8bed5554000c7cb
```

which needs a cookie, so I first store it on a file:

```
curl -c cookie-jar http://example.com/site-explorer/overview/subdomains/example.com
```

Trying curl with these values:

```
curl -b cookie-jar -A "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)" --referer "http://example.com/site-explorer/overview/subdomains/example.com" http://example.com/site-explorer/get_overview_text_data.php?data_type=refdomains_stats&hash=19a53c6b9aab3917d8bed5554000c7cb
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one problem which leaps out at me: You aren't quoting the URL, which means that characters such as `&` and `?` will be interpreted by the shell instead of getting passed to `curl`. If you're using a totally static URL, enclose it in single quotes, as in `'http://blah.com/blah/blah...'`.